# JQuery Ajax button isn't working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am extremely new at writing ajax and working with a restful api... so, bear with me.

I have a Laravel 5.2 RESTful API that I am using on the backend, and I'm attempting to simply load a list of categories using Jquery / Ajax. As you click through the categories, each child category loads fine, but I cannot seem to get the "back" button to work (by this, I mean the LI I am generating, not the browser back button). When you click it, it shows the alert - and the data is correct, but that's it. The list doesn't refresh and populate with the appropriate items.

**EDIT**

There are no errors being thrown to the javascript console either. It just won't populate from the ajax call.

**EDIT**

I removed the request.abort() right after I made the original post.

**EDIT**

Here is the JSON returned from the URL api/categories/4 - as an example.

[{"id":6,"parent":4,"name":"sub_subcat4_1","slug":"sub_subcat4_1","description":null,"created_at":null,"updated_at":null},{"id":7,"parent":4,"name":"sub_subcat4_2","slug":"sub_subcat4_2","description":null,"created_at":null,"updated_at":null}]

**EDIT**

Here is the HTML for the #categories

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-12">
    <ul id="categories">
    </ul>
</div>
```

**The Javascript**

```
    <script>
    /*
     * This loads the default / root categories.
     */
    function getRootCategories() {
        $.getJSON("api/categories", function(data) {
            var categories = [];
            $("#categories").html("");
            $.each(data, function(key, val) {
                $("#categories").append("<li class='subcat' data-id='" + val.id + "' onClick='getSubcats(this);'>" + val.name + '</li>');
            });
        });
    }

    /*
     * This loads the sub categories if there's any data returned. Otherwise, just leave the user where they are.
     */
    function getSubcats(cat) {
        var dataID = cat.getAttribute("data-id");
        alert(dataID);
        if(dataID == "null") {
            getRootCategories();
        }
        else {
            $.getJSON("api/categories/" + dataID, function (data) {
                if (data.length != 0) {
                    $("#categories").html("");
                    var newCats = '';
                    var parent = '';
                    $.each(data, function (key, val) {
                        parent = "<li class='subcat' data-id='" + val.parent + "' onClick='getSubcats(this);'>Back</li>";
                        newCats += "<li class='subcat' data-id='" + val.id + "' onClick='getSubcats(this);'>" + val.name + '</li>';
                    });
                    $("#categories").append(parent + newCats);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajaxSetup({ cache:false });
        getRootCategories();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: What exactly is `request.abort();` doing, there is no `request` ?

Comment: Add an error handler to the getJSON call see if it called

Comment: You might need to share HTML as well for `#categories` element. Remove statement `$("#categories").html("");` from get sub category function. Also consider `parent +=` for parent variable String.

Comment: Did you add the error handler? and do you realize `null` is not `"null"` So add fail and see if it gets triggered: `$.getJSON(...).fail(function(){ console.log(arguments); });`

Comment: if I remove the `$("#categories").html("");` from the subcategory function, it just makes the list get longer and longer. It also keeps reposting the same thing that's already on the screen... which makes me think it's not actually using the correct URL to post back to.

Comment: I added 

`.fail(function(jqxhr, textStatus, error) {
     console.log("Request Failed: " + textStatus + " - " + error);
 });`

There's nothing going to the console.

Yes, I know that null != "null", however, its using a string, not actual null value.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I just had my variables all mixed up. I wasn't setting the correct parent id.

The new script looks like this -

```
    <script>
    var previous = null;
    /*
     * This loads the default / root categories.
     */
    function getRootCategories() {
        $.getJSON("api/categories", function(data) {
            var categories = [];
            $("#categories").html("");
            $.each(data, function(key, val) {
                $("#categories").append("<li class='subcat' data-parent='" + val.parent + "' data-id='" + val.id + "' onClick='getSubcats(this);'>" + val.name + '</li>');
                previous = val.parent;
            });
        });
    }

    /*
     * This loads the sub categories if there's any data returned. Otherwise, just leave the user where they are.
     */
    function getSubcats(cat) {
        var dataID = cat.getAttribute("data-id");
        previous = cat.getAttribute("data-parent");

        if(dataID == "null") {
            getRootCategories();
        }
        else {
            $.getJSON("api/categories/" + dataID, function (data) {
                if (data.length != 0) {
                    $("#categories").html("");
                    var newCats = '';
                    var parent = '';
                    $.each(data, function (key, val) {
                        parent = "<li class='subcat' data-id='" + previous + "' onClick='getSubcats(this);'>Back</li>";
                        newCats += "<li class='subcat' data-parent='" + val.parent + "' data-id='" + val.id + "' onClick='getSubcats(this);'>" + val.name + '</li>';
                    });
                    $("#categories").append(parent + newCats);

                }
            })
            .fail(function(jqxhr, textStatus, error) {
                console.log("Request Failed: " + textStatus + " - " + error);
            });
        }
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajaxSetup({ cache:false });
        getRootCategories();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: In that case, you should just delete this question ;)

Comment: Instead of leaving it here for someone else to find and maybe get help from?

Comment: Honestly, this is more of a typo type situation and is not likely to be helpful to future searchers